# Show list items on page

Tags: orchardcms

I have a menu item called: **Offer** that has sub items that link to pages:

- Offer Category A
- Offer Category B
- Offer Category C

I also have a content type called **Offer Item**. Content items of this type have tags:

- offer-a
- offer-b
- offer-c

So far, in order to display a list of **Offer Items X** on **Offer Category X** page I did:

- create a query for each category (query-offer-a, query-offer-b, query-offer-c) based on tags
- create a layer for each category page with match condition, for instance:

  url '~/category-a'
- create a widget for each category, where widget-x is visible only on layer-x. I've also set **For Query** parameter to query-offer-x

These are preety many steps to do a simple thing. To display list items on the page I have to:

1. Create a layer with match url confition
2. Create a query
3. Add a widget to a layer and link it to the query

Is there a easier way?

Comment: Flexibility comes at a cost

Comment: Combined your queries.